# Custom fonts are not rendered in RN-SVG <Text/>

Tags: javascript, react-native, font-family, react-native-svg

In my code I tried to:

```
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font'

useFonts( {
  'Robo Numbers':require( '../assets/fonts/my-custom.ttf' ),
} )
```

Now when I render the RN own or RN-Paper's `Text` element, the font-family properly shows up:

```
import { Text } from 'react-native-paper'
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  countdown:{
    fontFamily:'Robo Numbers', 
    fontSize:34,
  },
})

 <Text style={[ styles.countdown, { color:10 > countdown ? 'orange' : '#f8f0c1' } ]}>{countdown}</Text>
```

but in RN-SVG's `Text` the default font is rendered:

```
<Text stroke={10 > countdown ? 'orange' : '#f8f0c1'} fontFamily="Robo Numbers">{countdown}</Text>
```

Is the functionality missing in the library, or am I missing something?

Comment: Is that `fontFamily="…"` attribute processed into resulting element's style attribute value (or something) or just transferred verbatim? I guess that anything other than `style="…"` and few old-school presentational attributes must be pretty much ignored. (That being said … how does the rendered DOM exactly look like?)

Comment: it's react-native-svg's standard Text.fontFamily attribute which is NOT supposed to go into style. Also with DOM it has nothing to do

Comment: I see, it's https://reactnative.dev/docs/text in https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg, my bad. There seems to be bunch of platform-dependent issues related to custom fonts there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now `"react-native-svg": "~13.4.0"` the custom fonts are not supported or I could not find the DOCUMENTED way to use them.

Hence I found a pretty uncomplicated workaround based on `<ForeignObject/>`:

```
render() {
  const { countdown } = this.state

  return <>
    <ForeignObject x={85} y={94} height={14} key={countdown}>
      <Text style={{ fontFamily:'Robo Numbers' }}>{countdown}</Text>
    </ForeignObject>
  <>
}
```

The **CRITICAL** thing here is the `ForeignObject@key` attribute. It must be present to force the ForeignObject re-render it's children.

In my case I increment the countdown variable within `setInterval()`, but the text never got updated before I added the `ForeignObject@key` with ever changing value!

Hope this will help someone...